# Regexp to detect a word only if it is not part of longer word?

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regex that would match a word only of it is not part of a longer word.

Let's assume that the word is `failure', so here are some examples

- `failure bla bla` - should match
- `bla failure.` - should match
- `no-failure bla` - should not match

Mainly `failure` string needs not to have any `[\d\w-_]` around it in order to be considered part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're including the dash in the group of characters that constitute a word, you can't do it with word boundaries; you need lookaround assertions (which are supported by Java):

```
(?<![\w-])failure(?![\w-])
```

should do it.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<![\w-])  # Assert no alphanumeric or dash before the current position
failure     # Match "failure"
(?![\w-])   # Assert no alphanumeric or dash after the current position
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, an approach to make this work in JavaScript could be `(?=[^\w-]failure[^\w-])`. Maybe end and beginning of string has to be incorporated as well. Any thoughts about this (since it will test every position, I thought it might be bad)?

Comment: @FelixKling: Well, for one it will fail to match `failure` at the start or end of the string.

Comment: Yeah I was just editing my comment regarding this ;) Though this can easily fixed with `([^\w-]|^)` (and `$`). But I thought there might be other server problems...

Comment: `(?:^|[^\w-])failure(?![^\w-])` would work. Then of course the match result will include the character before `failure`.

Comment: Right, that's easier... I was just thinking about how negative lookbehinds could be simulated in JS. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your flavor of regex supports it, you can use `\b` to match on a word break, e.g. `/\bfailure\b/`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very good case for Regex.

Why not String.split to break it into words, then compare each word to your target (Since what you are saying is that it should only match if isolated by spaces).

Well, String.split DOES use Regex, but it's a lot more controlled and you really only need the default split on space, or maybe you want to add periods (So your second example would match).